# Select value from dataframe which minimises a criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A__area_ID' : np.arange(3),
                'B_demand' : (150, 300, 250),
                'C_sites' : (10, 20, 30),
                'D_supply' : (100, 200, 300),
                'E_margin' : (-50, -100, 50),
                'F_new_sites' : ('', '', '')})
```

I also have another dataframe with values obtained from a separate simulation:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'sites_lookup' : (5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40),
                'supply_lookup' : (50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400)})
```

I want to fill the 'F_new_sites' column with the minimum required cell tower sites (from df2.sites_lookup) to meet the demand for each area (every row is a specific geographical area).

'E_margin' is the capacity margin (supply - demand), so if the capacity is negative I want to add more cell sites.

The second dataframe (df2) indicates how much supply (supply_lookup) is provided by a set number of cell tower sites (sites_lookup).

I have wrongly attempted the following:

```
if df.E_margin < 0 :
    df.F_new_sites [df2.supply_lookup >= df.demand] = df2.sites_lookup
else = 0
```

I want the final dataframe to look like this, where 'E_new_sites' represents the total number of sites required to meet the demand present:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({ 'A__area_ID' : np.arange(3),
                    'B_demand' : (150, 300, 250),
                    'C_sites' : (10, 20, 30),
                    'D_supply' : (100, 200, 300),
                    'E_margin' : (-50, -100, 50),
                    'F_new_sites' : ('15', '30', '0')})
```

In some cases the demand and supply won't evenly match, so I need which ever bucket from supply_lookup exceeds the present demand (to guarantee meeting this level).

Comment: You're looking up `D_supply - E_margin` in the `supply_lookup` column? Then bringing the `sites_lookup` value over to `df['F_new_sites']`?

Comment: If E_margin is negative, make the B_demand and supply_lookup values match, and then put the correct sites_lookup value in F_new_sites. I hope that makes sense, Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming the dataframes for convenience:

```
sites_df = df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A__area_ID' : pd.np.arange(3),
                           'B_demand' : (150, 300, 250),
                           'C_sites' : (10, 20, 30),
                           'D_supply' : (100, 200, 300),
                           'E_margin' : (-50, -100, 50),
                           'F_new_sites' : ('', '', '')})
lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'sites_lookup' : (5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40),
                           'supply_lookup' : (50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400)})
```

Let's make a function to be `apply`'d to each dataframe row:

```
def lookup_new_sites(row):
    if row['E_margin'] < 0:
        # get the minimum number of sites that cover the current supply deficit
        number_new = lookup_df.loc[lookup_df['supply_lookup'] >= abs(row['E_margin']), 'sites_lookup'].values[0]
        return row['C_sites'] + number_new
    else:
        return 0
```

And apply it:

```
sites_df['F_new_sites'] = sites_df.apply(lookup_new_sites, axis=1)
```

Giving:

```
   A__area_ID  B_demand  C_sites  D_supply  E_margin  F_new_sites
0           0       150       10       100       -50           15
1           1       300       20       200      -100           30
2           2       250       30       300        50            0
```